# maxDisplays of CGGetDisplaysWithPoint

Tags: objective-c, macos

**Definition:**

As defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454385-cggetdisplayswithpoint?language=objc), CGGetDisplaysWithPoint takes 4 parameters:

- A CGPoint object
- An int32 representing the maximum number of displays returned
- A mutable array passed by reference, which will be filled with the displayIDs found.
- An int32 representing the matching display count

**Syntax:**

`CGError CGGetDisplaysWithPoint(CGPoint point, uint32_t maxDisplays, CGDirectDisplayID *displays, uint32_t *matchingDisplayCount);`

This is fine and I can get this function working however I am quite confused as to how I should deal with the maxDisplays parameter?

As I understand it, if I set maxDisplays to 5 then if someone has 6 displays, there is a 1/6 chance that a randomly selected pixel will find no displays?

So do we just set maxDisplays to something unrealistic, like 99, and release the array afterwards? What's the point in this argument?

Answer (score 2):

The point of the argument is to prevent the function from writing past the end of your array. You have to tell it the capacity of the array. Note that the `displays` parameter is neither a Cocoa nor Core Foundation mutable array object. It's a C-style array. It's "mutable" in the sense that it's not "const", but it's not an object that manages its own storage. You are responsible for managing that storage and must communicate its capacity to any function that is intended to store data in it (or otherwise guarantee that such function won't overrun it).

So, your question should really be how to decide on the capacity of the array. There are two basic approaches:

1) Call the function passing `NULL` for the `displays` parameter and any arbitrary value (best to use 0) for `maxDisplays`. As documented, when `displays` is `NULL`, `maxDisplays` is ignored and the function outputs via `matchingDisplayCount` the number of displays whose bounds contain the given point. Then, allocate an array with (at least) that many elements to use to receive the display IDs and call the function again, passing that array for `displays` and its capacity for `maxDisplays`.

2) Use an array with capacity of 32. It's not *explicitly* documented but it's implicit in the API that that's the maximum number of supported displays. A display ID can be converted to an OpenGL display mask using `CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask()`. The type `CGOpenGLDisplayMask` is used to hold OpenGL display masks. It is defined as `uint32_t`, a 32-bit value. Therefore, there can be at most 32 active displays.

This technique is used in some Apple docs, like [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1741/_index.html), [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/DisplayModes.html), [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2080/_index.html), and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1542/_index.html). That last one even makes a direct connection between the number of bits in `CGOpenGLDisplayMask` and the maximum number of displays.

Comment: I expect it would not work. Certainly a lot of code modeled on Apple's examples would break. Is that a concern of yours? ;)

Comment: Well actually that makes my life a lot easier! :P